# Failure to install something on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I keep getting an error on my Ubuntu whenever I try to install something.
Can anyone please help me solve this issue?
Below is the error message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bluez-alsa:i386 esound-common glib-networking:i386
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386
  gstreamer0.10-x:i386 gtk2-engines:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
  gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 gvfs:i386 gvfs-libs:i386
  ibus-gtk:i386 libaa1:i386 libaio1:i386 libao-common libao4:i386
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
  libasyncns0:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libaudio2:i386 libaudiofile1:i386
  libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
  libavc1394-0:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386
  libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libcanberra0:i386
  libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcgmanager0:i386 libcroco3:i386
  libcups2:i386 libcupsfilters1:i386 libcupsimage2:i386 libcurl3:i386
  libdatrie1:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libdv4:i386 libesd0:i386
  libexif12:i386 libflac8:i386 libfluidsynth1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386
  libfreetype6:i386 libgail-common:i386 libgail18:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386
  libgcrypt11:i386 libgd3:i386 libgdbm3:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
  libgettextpo0:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
  libglu1-mesa:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-port10:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libgudev-1.0-0:i386
  libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libibus-1.0-5:i386
  libice6:i386 libidn11:i386 libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjasper1:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libjson0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386
  libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmad0:i386
  libmikmod2:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libmysqlclient18:i386 libnspr4:i386
  libnss3:i386 libntdb1 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386
  liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386
  libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386
  libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libproxy1:i386
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp:i386
  libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-designer:i386
  libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386
  libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-scripttools:i386 libqt4-sql:i386
  libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqt4-xml:i386
  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386
  libqtwebkit4:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libreadline6:i386
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 librsvg2-2:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 librtmp0:i386
  libsamplerate0:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-mixer1.2:i386
  libsdl-net1.2:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386
  libsecret-1-0:i386 libshout3:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libspeex1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl0.9.8:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++5:i386
  libtag1-vanilla:i386 libtag1c2a:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtdb1:i386
  libthai0:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libudev1:i386 libunistring0:i386
  libusb-0.1-4:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386
  libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 libvorbis0a:i386
  libvorbisenc2:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libvpx1:i386 libwavpack1:i386
  libwebp5:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxaw7:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
  libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386
  libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxft2:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386
  libxmu6:i386 libxp6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386
  libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxtst6:i386
  libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-headers-3.13.0-68
  linux-headers-3.13.0-68-generic linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic linux-signed-image-3.13.0-68-generic
  mysql-common odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 odbcinst1debian2:i386 python-ntdb
  xaw3dg:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  udo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 208 kB of archives.
After this operation, 569 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe udo amd64 6.4.1-1 [208 kB]
Fetched 208 kB in 1s (137 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package udo.
(Reading database ... 353091 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/udo_6.4.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udo (6.4.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic (3.13.0-74.118) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-efi-amd64.config: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                      -generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.74.80); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-trusty:
 linux-image-generic-lts-trusty depends on linux-image-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-trusty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-3.13.0-74-generic:
 linux-signed-image-3.13.0-74-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic (= 3.13.0-74.118); however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-signed-image-3.13.0-74-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic (= 3.13.0-74.118); however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-3.13.0-74-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-signed-image-3.13.0-74-generic; however:
  Package linux-signed-image-3.13.0-74-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 3.13.0.74.80); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic-lts-trusty:
 linux-signed-generic-lts-trusty depends on linux-signed-generic; however:
  Package linux-signed-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic-lts-trusty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic-lts-trusty:
 linux-signed-image-generic-lts-trusty depends on linux-signed-image-generic; however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic-lts-trusty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up udo (6.4.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-trusty
 linux-signed-image-3.13.0-74-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
 linux-signed-generic-lts-trusty
 linux-signed-image-generic-lts-trusty
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Below is the output of   cat -net /etc/default/grub

```
 1  # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update$
 2  # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.$
 3  # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:$
 4  #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'$
 5  $
 6  GRUB_DEFAULT=0$
 7  #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0$
 8  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true$
 9  GRUB_TIMEOUT=10$
10  GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`$
11  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=M-bM-^@M-^\quiet splash nomodeset i8042.nomux $
12  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""$
13  $
14  # Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs$
15  # This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains$
16  # the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)$
17  #GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"$
18  $
19  # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)$
20  #GRUB_TERMINAL=console$
21  $
22  # The resolution used on graphical terminal$
23  # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE$
24  # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'$
25  #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480$
26  $
27  # Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux$
28  #GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true$
29  $
30  # Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries$
31  #GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"$
32  $
33  # Uncomment to get a beep at grub start$
34  #GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"$
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the output of `cat -net /etc/default/grub`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `M-bM-^@M-^\` sequence in line 11 of your `cat` output

```
11  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=M-bM-^@M-^\quiet splash nomodeset i8042.nomux $
```

indicates that the file has non-ASCII characters - most likely unicode smart quotes “ (maybe you copy-pasted the entry from a website or similar). This is preventing the file from being parsed by the `update-grub` command, and the remaining errors likely follow on from that failure.

You will need to edit the file with a plain text editor such as `nano` or `vi`

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and make sure it contains only ASCII text e.g.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

(replacing smart quotes with plain ASCII quotes `"` if that is indeed the problem).

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem. Thank you!